# Database connection is not active

Tags: php, mysql, ezsql

I updated to the latest PHP and MySQL versions today, and ezSQL (2.17) as well.

Now things initially connect fine, however when using `$db->select` it throws this error:

```
mySQL database connection is not active in /data/servers/shared/class.sql.php on line 120
```

Anyone know what is happening?

Comment: Why are you using eZSQL? [Be a better PHP developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Probably need to see you connection code as well.  On a side note, that is not a great SQL wrapper.  It uses the old and outdated mysql_* functions.  I would look into something else to handle queries that utilizes PDO or mysqli at minimum.

Comment: read http://forums.hotarucms.org/archive/index.php/t-884.html

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I installed php5-pdo_mysql and modified the ezSQL PDO to my needs.